# Does rooting an android device effect its activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I wrote a test application for testing the `life cycle` methods. The application starting an activity 'B' from an activity 'A'. From what I learned in the [developer's manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), 'A' should stop and then 'B' gets created, but my device has a different behavior, 'A' pauses and 'B' gets created when 'B' is popped of the back stack `onResume()` method of 'A' is getting called. Now I ran the same application on my dad's device and it gives the expected result. My question is does rooting alter the `life cycle` of the device, if so is there a way I can make it "normal" without un-rooting my device. Thanks in advance.

The screen shot of log file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B65sqxYLjUTzYi12N1NTVmpPcTA/edit)

**EDIT:** MY device , moto x first generation(xt1052) runs on android 4.4.4, my dad's device, moto g first generation runs on android 5.0,2

Comment: No rooting does not affect the lifecycle in any way. But why would you be surprised that `onResume()` and `onPause()` are called? That is completely normal, in fact I would be worried if those methods are not being called. `onStart()` and `onStop()` are only being called when the `Activity` first starts or before it is being killed. I can only think of one situation in which you might experience a lifecycle like on your dad's device: If it has really bad hardware and can't keep the `Activity` in the background, but instead has to immediately kill it to save resources.

Comment: but onStop() gets called every time the activity becomes invisible. quoting the developer's manual "For example, onStop() is called when a new activity starts and this one is no longer visible". My device doesn't call onStop() in this scenario

Comment: What version of android did you experience this behavior? Reading the current life cycle documentation, there are no longer exceptions to when onStop gets called.

Comment: It is Android KitKat 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Your question talks about two distinct life cycle events.

1. Activity A starts Activity B. Here is what the manual says:

> When Activity A starts Activity B, Activity A is stopped, but the
>   system retains its state (such as scroll position and text entered
>   into forms). If the user presses the Back button while in Activity B,
>   Activity A resumes with its state restored.

2. From Activity B, user presses back popping Activity A from the back stack:

> If the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped
>   from the stack and destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is
>   resumed. When an activity is destroyed, the system does not retain the
>   activity's state.

It is unclear which one of these you are saying does not seem to operate correctly on a rooted device. However, I suspect you are conflating the two and things work correctly.

EDIT:

Your comment indicates confusion about language used in the manual versus the names of lifecycle methods. When the manual says (in case 1) that the activity is stopped, that doesn't mean onStop(). The context of that description indicates that onPause() would be called - if the user presses the back button, the activity resumes suggesting onResume() will be called. To transition to onStop() and thus require transition back to onRestart() in order to resume the application, the back stack would need to lose more context - as in the user completely exits the running application (and so it no longer makes sense to keep it's back stack) and starts another.

Comment: I'm talking about the first one, the activity A starts activity B, but in my case the lifecycle method onStop() is not getting called

Comment: @AnirudhAlameluvari onStop() is called prior to complete destruction of your activity or if it's being put down for a "deep" sleep. The manual clearly states that Activity A is placed in a state where it can be resumed. That won't happen if onStop runs.

Comment: @iheanyi - no.  onStop() simply refers to the Activity no longer being visible on screen.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I retract my previous comment, the current documentation states that onStop is to be called when the app is no longer visible. So the question becomes, what version of android is the OP using? Because the onStop behavior has changed since I last dealt with this problem.

Comment: No, it hasn't changed - onStop() has always had this purpose.  onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() each have a fundamentally unique meaning.  That said, the circumstances in which an activity is destroyed (and indeed, the rarer cases where its process is killed without onDestroy() notification) can vary from version to version, device to device, and even in different situations on the same device in different trials.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us the 2 cenarios where the application is running:

The device you have, the version/build number, and the Manufacturer

The other device, the version/build number and the Manufacturer.

From my experience so far, the same device, when assembled by different manufacturers come with the Operational System altered, sometimes in major ways.
I had an application that used the SMS system, that was unable to start in an specific system, due to the manufacturer overriding the user permissions.

Likewise, there can be the following cenarios that change the behavior:

- Device has less memory than what it needs available, and kills the Activities to release memory
- Device has hidden user that can change the flow of your apps
- Device has a "written" version of the Android, but runs another or is not complete
- Device has different compiled libraries, whose function are out of order (or have been replaced)

To bypass those issues, I suggest looking at onPause() and onResume(), as those seem to behave closer on different devices, and different operational systems, [check this for additional aid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If you need a separate onPause from an onStop(), you might need to "branch" your application, making subtle changes in code, for each version

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden" user?. I don't think the first one or the last one are the reasons. also what do you mean by "written" version

Comment: I am from Brazil, in here, there is a system where the GSM signal dealership can do a "consignment contract", in wich they lower the equipment price, but locks the Operational system with changes, For instance, they can "lock" the SMS permissions to their own apps, and do not allow common users to remove those apps